# Select highest value in a column with other column values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

My table looks like this:

[image]

And I want to get highest bid amount for a specific product, with the row id. My query is like this

```
SELECT 
    MAX(BidAmount) as highestBid,id
FROM 
    [wf_bid]  
WHERE
    ProductId = 101 AND ClientId = 101  
GROUP BY
    id
```

I expect only one row with highest `BidAmount`, but the query returns all rows with this product id and client id. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: pls update question with create script and some dummy data  your condition

Comment: Do you have an example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sub-query ? If you have multiple records with same BidAmount, then it return top 1.

```
 SELECT TOP 1
      BidAmount as highestBid,id
  FROM [wf_bid] WHERE BidAmount = (Select Max(BidAmount) FROM [wf_bid] WHERE ProductId=101 and ClientId=101)
```

Comment: throws this error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my answer. Where clause was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number() and select the first row:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT
     id,
     BidAmount,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BidAmount desc) as rn
   FROM
     [wf_bid]
   WHERE ProductId = 101 and ClientId = 101
) i
WHERE
   i.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this way:

```
SELECT id,highestBid from
(Select Max(BidAmount)highestBid,productID,clientid FROM [wf_bid] WHERE ProductId=101 and ClientId=101) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id,productID,clientid FROM [wf_bid]) as b
where a.productID = b.productid and a.clientid = b.clientid
```

Comment: You should be **consistent** about how you spell your SQL keywords - either use ALL UPPERCASE, or "all lowercase", or "Mixed" - pick any one of those and **stick to it** - don't change your spelling with each keyword - that's just a mess .....

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

try this way,

```
select * FROM
(SELECT
     id,
     BidAmount,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (parrtition by ProductId ORDER BY BidAmount desc) as rn
   FROM
     [wf_bid]
     WHERE ClientId = 101)t4
     where rn=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in the group by ID, it doesn't work that way because it isn't "adding your bids" it is telling you the max number of every ID not just which is the biggest bid and it's ID. I'm guessing you'll get what you want if you delete group by id. If not you would need to explain your need further.